# Package and chunk large directory for transfer

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, system.io.packaging

I have a folder structure that is about 7 levels deep, and contains about 1.0 million files of various sizes and formats.  Everything in it that could be compressed has been.  It's about 350GB.

I want to push this entire directory into cloud storage.

I was wondering if there's a way to package the whole directory in a tar or rar file or something, chunk it up and send it.  Then I could recreate the package (unchunk) in a cloud service and then unpackage if needed.  And do this as quickly as possible.

Is there a way using `System.Io.Packaging` for example to NOT try to compress the directory structure but just package it?  I think there is- but I don't know if this is efficient, or in  fact if I am thinking about this the right way.

Maybe there's a better way to push this large directory structure into the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to copy your folder structure on your file system to cloud storage, you can use command line utility – AzCopy to do that. This utility is designed to simplify the task of transferring data in to and out of a azure storage account. You can read more about AzCopy on our blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/04/07/azcopy-support-for-read-access-geo-redundant-account.aspx).